# How to do a Sum() with condition?

Tags: dynamic, sql-server-2012, sum, grouping, case-when

I have a Table like this

```
+----+------+-----+
| ID | Type | Qty |
+----+------+-----+
| 1  | 1    | 10  |
| 2  | 1    | 10  |
| 3  | 2    | 15  |
| 4  | 1    | 20  |
| 5  | 2    | 10  |
+----+------+-----+
```

How to do a dynamic sum based on condition "Type" field.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Type, 
    CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN SUM(Qty) 
         ELSE Qty 
    END AS SumQty
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ??
```

And i want a result like this:

```
+------+--------+
| Type | SumQty |
+------+--------+
| 1    | 40     |
| 2    | 15     |
| 2    | 10     |
+------+--------+
```

I know i can do this with a UNION clause. But if you know a dynamic query to achieved that result, please tell me.
Any solution would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: A dynamic query is just one built at run time rather than known in advance. It's not mutually exclusive with a query containing a union clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two queries, one for the type you want and one for all others, then union them together, something like:

```
select type, sum(qty) as sumqty from tbl where type = 1 group by type
union all
select type, qty as sumqty from tbl where type <> 1
```

Testing this in [`sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com):

```
create table tbl (id int, type int, qty int);
insert into tbl (id, type, qty) values (1, 1, 10);
insert into tbl (id, type, qty) values (2, 1, 10);
insert into tbl (id, type, qty) values (3, 2, 15);
insert into tbl (id, type, qty) values (4, 1, 20);
insert into tbl (id, type, qty) values (5, 2, 10);
===
select type, sum(qty) as sumqty from tbl where type = 1 group by type
union all
select type, qty as sumqty from tbl where type <> 1
```

gives you what you desire:

```
type    sumqty
----    ------
   1        40
   2        15
   2        10
```

Comment: I know i can do that with a UNION clause. But how if not using a UNION clause?

Comment: @user3867892, my advice is to use the union rather than faffing about trying to find another way based on some artificial limitation. It really is the easiest way. Of course, if you have a valid reason for the limitation, feel free to let us know so we can adjust our approach.

Comment: yes the reason because i have a tons of query and i can't using UNION to do a same query, although with a different condition.

Comment: @user3867892: in that case you can build the query dynamically based on the values you do and don't want aggregated (using `in` and `not in` if it's more complex than a simple equality/inequality or two-range check). This will *include* the union clause and then you run the dynamically generated query. As I said in my comment to the question, they're not mutually exclusive.